# Load tables only with some specific conditions (@Where)

Tags: jpa

What I'm trying to do is to load only promotions with promotion.enabled=1 AND PromotionType.enabled=1. 
I tried to add the `@Where` annotation in both tables but when I set promotionType, enabled to 0 I´m getting an error.
On the other hand, I also tried to add the `@WhereJoinTable` clause to promotionType but I'm not getting the expected result. Any help?

The first one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOTEL_PROMOTION")
@Where(clause = "enabled=1")
public class Promotion implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 257070400893576505L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROMOTION_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
    private Long priority;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROMOTION_TYPE_ID")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "enabled=1")
    private PromotionType promotionType;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    private Boolean enabled;
}
```

The second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOTEL_PROMOTION_TYPE")
public class PromotionType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8359165117733458987L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROMOTION_TYPE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "STYLE")
    private String style;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    private Boolean enabled;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: I´m fetching Promotions with promotionType.enabled=0 and promotionType.enabled=1 and I only need to get Promotions with promotionType.enabled=1.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you explain it better? From what I understood, you need to fetch `Promotion` with `promotionType.enabled = 1` but you are getting some error? If so, what is that error?

Comment: Also, Can you try using `@Where(clause = "enabled=true")`?

Comment: When I added the annotation to both tables `@Where(clause="enabled=1)` I´m getting an error because I´m loading only the ones with promotionType.enabled=1 in the PromotionType table. When loading the Promotion table, I´m trying to fetch all the promotions with enabled=0 and enabled=1, and that´s the reason I´m getting this error:

`Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.resources.domain.service.entity.PromotionType with id 12`.

After seeing this error, I removed the `@Where` clause to PromotionType however I´m not getting what I really want.

Comment: The reason for this error is, in table `HOTEL_PROMOTION`, you have a field with `PROMOTION_TYPE_ID =12` which was not found in `HOTEL_PROMOTION_TYPE` table. Can you delete that entry and check again?

Comment: Exactly, that´s the reason. That PromotionType with Id=12 is not loaded because enabled was set to 0. That´s OK. The problem comes when I try to load a Promotion with with promotionType id=12 (the disabled one). No this promotion should be discarded. To sum up (I need to load only the ones with Promotion.enabled=1 AND PromotionType.enabled=1)

BTW: I cannot delete it, maybe I´ll need it in the future.